# Debugging STM32F767 with OpenOCD - unknown device id problem

Tags: debugging, stm32, openocd, nucleo, stm32f7

Trying to debug STM32F767 (NUCLEO-F767ZI board) with OpenOCD 0.10.0 in VSCode I get the following error:

```
Info : device id = 0xa05f0000
Warn : Cannot identify target as a STM32 family.
Error: auto_probe failed
```

Does it mean OpenOCD simply does not support this MCU?
How do I go about solving it?
I attach **launch.json** configuration below.

```
"name": "Debug (OpenOCD)",
"type":"cortex-debug",
"request": "launch",
"servertype":"openocd",
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"executable": "${workspaceRoot}/BUILD/NUCLEO_F767ZI/GCC_ARM-DEBUG/${workspaceRootFolderName}.elf",
"svdFile": "${workspaceRoot}/STM32F7x7.svd",
"runToMain": true,
"device": "STM32F767ZI",
"searchDir": ["C:/Program Files/OpenOCD/scripts"],
"configFiles": [
    "/interface/stlink.cfg",
    "/target/stm32f7x.cfg",
]
```

Comment: `0xa05f0000` doesn't look like the correct CPU id. It should return `0x5BA02477`. Do you have the CN4 jumpers in the correct position? Have you connected the board via the CN1 USB connector?

Comment: st-util correctly (I think) reports Chip ID is 0x0000001a, Core ID is 0x5ba02477 but besides that does not work as well. CN4 jumper are ON, all other jumpers in default position. I am able to load simple blinky app using st-link via usb, firmware is the latest V2.J37.M26

Comment: I think incorrect chip id is what causes the problem. This MCU should have Chip ID = 0x451. Perhaps it is incorrectly read/parsed.